# Does head consume additional characters from stdin?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I execute the following `head` command:

```
yes 123456789 | ( head -n 1; head -n 1 )
```

I get:

```
123456789
3456789
```

While I would expect:

```
123456789
123456789
```

It also puzzles me that when I execute:

```
echo -e "123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n" | \
( head -n 1; head -n 1 )
```

I get:

```
123456789
```

instead of:

```
123456789
123456789
```

I guess there is something that I do not understand. Do you know why I get this behaviour?

Comment: you simply cannot know how many characters the previous process has consumed. those commands don't make sense.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: In this case, I don't think it's the previous command. Since the IO is buffered and therefore split between the two `head` commands, it seems like the second `head` may be reading earlier than what is available on the stream. I don't know the mechanics behind this but with the parenthese, the IO seems to be split between the two processes. Not that the first one necessarily consumed more. The parentheses creates a sub-shell. If you remove the parentheses, the second one just sits there waiting for input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Input and output are completely different beasts. The manual of `head` tell you what is the expected *output*, but it doesn't tell you anything about how the *input* is processed.

So the short answer is: you're relying on undocumented things.

Now, if you are interested to know what's going behind the scenes, you can add some tracing

```
| ( strace head -n 1; tail )
```

in your 2nd example: *Note: sorry for the strace format, I'm on cygwin at the moment.*:

```
[...]
 24   35374 [main] head 1784 read: 51 = read(0, 0x22C700, 1024)
```

the first `head` process is trying to read the input, by reading a big chunk(1024 bytes), then probably looking for a newline character in the buffer. At least, that's how I would implement it. As you can see, it processed all 51 characters, so there's nothing left for the next process.

in your 1st example: the main difference here is that we have an endless input, so even though the first `head` will read a big chunk, there's also input left for the second process. The boundary will be arbitrary, it depends on the chunk size, implementation of head, how fread (buffered IO) is implemented an so on. For example, on my system, this was the output:

```
123456789
56789
```

Comment: Adding that the parentheses are key because it executes the command in a sub-shell. If you remove the parentheses, the process just sits there. It multiplies the pipe to both processes, essentially

Comment: of course it just sits there, it's just a `head -n 1` waiting to receive something on stdin...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `head` is definitely reading more than one line. It will be doing buffered I/O. Reading from a file, it appears to read by lines, but from a pipe, it's reading something like 512 bytes at a time. That would be consistent with what you see. The `3456789` is probably not the 2nd line, but the 52nd. To experiment with this, use something where you can tell the lines apart instead of `yes`. `cat somefile |` works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

(Late answer here.)

While the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148185/2235132) explains the reason behind what you observe, you could use a workaround to get the *expected output*.

Pipe the output to something that would *line buffer* the output:

```
$ yes 123456789 | { head -n 1; head -n 1; }
123456789
56789
$ yes 123456789 | grep --line-buffered . | { head -n 1; head -n 1; }
123456789
123456789
```

<sub>Note that I've used `{ ... }`, i.e. *command grouping*, which unlike `( ... )` doesn't create a subshell.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't always work. Rarely I got:

    $ yes 123445 | grep --line-buffered . | {head -n 2; head -n 3}
    123445
    123445
    3445
    123445
    123445

Also:

    $ seq 100 | grep --line-buffered . | {head -n 2; head -n 3}
    1
    2
    89
    90
    91

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get

```
123456789
123456789
```

then you need something like this:

```
yes 123456789 | head -2
```

(yes loop until pipe breaks, head -2 gives you 2 lines)

And for the second part it should be following to get what you want :)

```
echo -e "123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n" | head -2
```