# Get first line of a shell command's output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

While trying to read the version number of `vim`, I get a lot additional lines which I need to ignore. I tried to read the manual of `head` and tried the following command:

```
vim --version | head -n 1
```

I want to know if this is the correct approach?

Comment: How did it fail? It works for me.

Comment: Syntax is correct.what's the error..?

Comment: That works for me, but perhaps you are using a version of vim that writes version info to stderr.  Try `vim --version 2>&1 | sed 1q`

Comment: Works for me too -- so yes, your approach is correct `:)` Check whether your package outputs that info on `stderr` as @WilliamPursell provides a check for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2439587/1135424

Comment: vim --version | sed q | sed 's/(.*//'  # also strip off trailing blurb

Comment: This works on Ubuntu operating system version 16

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Yes, that is one way to get the first line of output from a command.

If the command outputs anything to standard error that you would like to capture in the same manner, you need to redirect the standard error of the command to the standard output stream:

```
utility 2>&1 | head -n 1
```

There are many other ways to capture the first line too, including `sed 1q` (quit after first line), `sed -n 1p` (only print first line, but read everything), `awk 'FNR == 1'` (only print first line, but again, read everything) etc.

Comment: "head -1" works too

Comment: @Kusalananda what about the nth/second line using this same method?

Comment: @dani'SOlearnvaluenewbies' I would likely use `sed -n 2p` for that, or you could do `head -n 2` piped to `tail -n 1` if you want to avoid `sed` for whatever reason.

Comment: Warning! Most of the time, `head` will read more than just the first line, so be careful when you need to also read stdin **after** the first line. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147693/does-head-consume-additional-characters-from-stdin

Answer (score 9):

I would use:

```
awk 'FNR <= 1' file_*.txt
```

As @Kusalananda points out there are many ways to capture the first line in command line but using the `head -n 1` may not be the best option when using wildcards since it will print additional info. Changing `'FNR == i'` to `'FNR <= i'` allows to obtain the first i lines.

For example, if you have n files named file_1.txt, ... file_n.txt:

```
awk 'FNR <= 1' file_*.txt

hello
...
bye
```

But with `head` wildcards print the name of the file:

```
head -1 file_*.txt

==> file_1.csv <==
hello
...
==> file_n.csv <==
bye
```

Comment: See `head -qn1 file_*.txt`

Comment: This is helpful if the output will be piped to `awk` later. We can combine to make it short and faster. For examples, `ls -lt *.tar | awk '{if (FNR <= 1) print $NF}'`